# TFS Powershell Install-Module not found

Tags: powershell, tfs

I've written the PS script below to 7zip a folder using 7Zip4Powershell however when during the build it fails with the following error:

```
Install-Module : The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At C:\Build\Work\19\s\DevOps\7zCompress.ps1:3 char:5
+ Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser -Name 7Zip4PowerShell -Verbose -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Install-Module:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
Compress-7Zip : The term 'Compress-7Zip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Build\Work\19\s\DevOps\7zCompress.ps1:18 char:1
+ Compress-7Zip -Path $sourcedir -ArchiveFileName $filename -CompressionLevel $com ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Compress-7Zip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
Process completed with exit code 0 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream.
```

Script

```
param([string]$sourcedir, [string]$filename, [string]$compressionLevel, [string]$compressionMethod)
If (-not (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name 7Zip4PowerShell)) {
    Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser -Name 7Zip4PowerShell -Verbose -Force
}

If(Test-Path $filename) {
    Remove-Item $filename
}

If (-not $compressionLevel) {
    $compressionLevel = "Normal"
}

If (-not $compressionMethod) {
    $compressionMethod = "Lzma2"
}

Compress-7Zip -Path $sourcedir -ArchiveFileName $filename -CompressionLevel $compressionLevel -CompressionMethod $compressionMethod
```

How do I get TFS 2015 On-Premises to recognize the Install-Module is a valid command? I've already installed the MSI for Install-Module on that machine. Do I perhaps need to add it as a build agent capability?

Comment: Change `Install-Module` to `Import-Module`?

Comment: Yeah with @gms0ulman above, there isn't an Install-Module, you want to Import it into the session.

Comment: There is an `install-module` (if you have package management installed) but `get-module` is showing here that the module is already available locally so he should just import it.

Comment: Are you able to run the script manually on the build agent?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

According to your error message , double check your powershell version in the build agent machine.

Cause from Powershell 5.0 onwards you , you will be able to use the cmdlet to *Install-Module*, *Save-Module*. If you are using the lower version of PS, will get similar error.

You could also manually RDP to the build agent with the build service account and run the PS script. This will narrow down if the issue is related to the environment or your build definition.